# Interact with a MediaObject in Internet Explorer through VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, activex

I'm trying to paste string values to a form on the page.
I have to use Internet Explorer - that's an old intranet system which works only in IE.

The form is not detected by a DOM Explorer - when I hover a mouse over it, it doesn't show anything. See screenshot below.
[image: a form where I need to enter text via VBA]

From what I've found the form is called a MediaObject -an ActiveX control:
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/JD%20Edwards%20EnterpriseOne/1056203_1.html

I didn't find any examples on how to interact with it. Googling the keywords "MediaObject" and "VBA" lead me here:
https://www.blackbaud.com/docs/default-source/how-to-documentation/blackbaud-student-information-system/system/vaeesis.pdf

Unfortunately, this PDF does not provide a code for classes / forms used, so I don't know to create a reference in my case.

Investigating source HTML code of the web page didn't help me too - it does not render this object. Here's the HTML code:

```html
<HTML><HEAD><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/jde/owportal/portal.css">
<SCRIPT>
var enterpriseOneContext = '/jde';
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="/jde/share/js/webgui.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript1.2>
<!--
//Global Variables
document.ActivEraPortal="True";
document.OneWorldPortal="2.3";
document.jdeowpWarnUser=false;
document.jdeowpWarningMessage="Clicking on this link will result in closing down any components or applications that may be running. You should save all of your work before continuing. Would you like to follow this link anyway?";
document.jdeowpFormInterconnect="";
document.jdeowpCriticalStateString="";

//Initializations
setCookie("com_jdedwards_CSN","");

//Javascript functions
function getLayout(sel)
{
    if ( !jdeowpWarningCheck() ){ return; }
    if(sel.selectedIndex < 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        window.location="http://parentdomain.domain.com:80/jde/servlet/com.jdedwards.portal.PortalBuilderServlet?workspace="+sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}


//Javascript functions
function jdeowpHandleLogoff()
{
    window.location="http://parentdomain.domain.com:80/jde/servlet/com.jdedwards.portal.PortalBuilderServlet?jdeLoginAction=LOGOUT";
}



//Javascript functions
function viewByRole(sel)
{
    if ( !jdeowpWarningCheck() ){ return; }
    if(sel.selectedIndex < 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        window.location="http://parentdomain.domain.com:80/jde/servlet/com.jdedwards.portal.PortalBuilderServlet?jdeowpviewrole="+sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}


//Javascript functions
function getTabLayout(workspaceDesc)
{
        window.location="http://parentdomain.domain.com:80/jde/servlet/com.jdedwards.portal.PortalBuilderServlet?workspace="+workspaceDesc;
}

function getCookie(name)
{
    var cookies = document.cookie;
    var start = cookies.indexOf(name+"=");
    if (start==-1)
        return "";
    start=cookies.indexOf("=",start)+1;
    var end=cookies.indexOf(";",start);
    if (end==-1)
        end=cookies.length;
    var value=unescape(cookies.substring(start,end));
    if (value==null)
        return "";
    return value;
}

function setCookie(name, value)
{
    var sysdate = new Date();
    var millis = sysdate.getTime()+10000;
    sysdate = new Date(millis);
    document.cookie=name+"="+escape(value)+"; expires="+sysdate.toGMTString()+";";
}

//These functions enable critical state which is only available via JavaScript
function jdeowpAddCSNotification(compname, value, type)
{
    var currentCookie = document.jdeowpCriticalStateString;
    if (currentCookie.length>0)
        currentCookie+="|";
    currentCookie+=compname+"|"+value+"|"+type;
    document.jdeowpCriticalStateString = currentCookie;
}

function jdeowpAddCSNotificationURL(compname, value)
{
    jdeowpAddCSNotification(compname, value, 1);
}

function jdeowpAddCSNotificationClass(compname, value)
{
    jdeowpAddCSNotification(compname, value, 0);
}

function jdeowpCSWarnUser()
{
    document.jdeowpWarnUser=true;
}

function jdeowpsetCSWarningMesssage(message)
{
    document.jdeowpWarningMessage=message;
}

function jdeowpWarningCheck()
{
    var bool = true;

    if (document.jdeowpWarnUser)
        bool=  confirm (document.jdeowpWarningMessage);

    if (bool && document.jdeowpCriticalStateString!="")
        setCookie("com_jdedwards_CSN", document.jdeowpCriticalStateString);

    return bool;

}

//JavaScript functions implemented for backward compatablility only
function showPage(compname, type, uri, addextra)
{
    //Build URL
    var buildurl;
    buildurl  = "http://parentdomain.domain.com:80/jde/servlet/com.jdedwards.portal.PortalBuilderServlet";
    buildurl += "?jdeowpcompname="+compname;
    buildurl += "&jdeowpcompstate="+type;
    buildurl += "&jdeowpcompaddextra="+addextra;
    var questionIdx = uri.indexOf("?");
    if ( (questionIdx != -1) && (uri.length > 0) )
    {
        var newUri = "";
        if (questionIdx > 0)
            newUri += uri.substring(0, questionIdx);
        newUri += "&";
        if (questionIdx < uri.length-1)
            newUri += uri.substring(questionIdx+1, uri.length);
        uri = newUri;
    }
    buildurl += "&jdeowpcompurl="+uri;
    window.location=buildurl;
}

function showOWPage(compname, type, uri, addextra)
{
    //Build URL
    var buildurl;
    buildurl  = "http://parentdomain.domain.com:80/jde/servlet/com.jdedwards.portal.PortalBuilderServlet";
    buildurl += "?jdeowpcompname="+compname;
    buildurl += "&jdeowpcompstate="+type;
    buildurl += "&jdeowpcompaddextra="+addextra;
    var questionIdx = uri.indexOf("?");
    if ( (questionIdx != -1) && (uri.length > 0) )
    {
        var newUri = "";
        if (questionIdx > 0)
            newUri += uri.substring(0, questionIdx);
        newUri += "&";
        if (questionIdx < uri.length-1)
            newUri += uri.substring(questionIdx+1, uri.length);
        uri = newUri;
    }
    buildurl += "&jdeowpcompclass="+uri;
    window.location=buildurl;
}

function showPersonalizationPage(compname, uri, addextra)
{
    showPage(compname, "4", uri, addextra );
}

function showHelpPage(compname, uri,addextra)
{
    showPage(compname, "3", uri, addextra);
}

function showMaxPage(compname, uri, addextra)
{
    showPage(compname, "2", uri, addextra);
}

function showLinkPage(compname, uri, addextra)
{
    showPage(compname, "7", uri, addextra);
}

function showFrameLinkPage(compname, uri, addextra)
{
    showPage(compname, "6", uri, addextra);
}
function showOWPersonalizationPage(compname, uri, addextra)
{
    showOWPage(compname, "4", uri, addextra );
}

function showOWHelpPage(compname, uri,addextra)
{
    showOWPage(compname, "3", uri, addextra);
}

function showOWMaxPage(compname, uri, addextra)
{
    showOWPage(compname, "2", uri, addextra);
}

function showOWLinkPage(compname, uri, addextra)
{
    showOWPage(compname, 7, uri, addextra);
}

function showOWFrameLinkPage(compname, uri, addextra)
{
    showOWPage(compname, "6", uri, addextra);
}

function showerrmsg()
{
    return;
}

function RunOWApp(formID)
{
    //Build URL
    var buildurl;
    buildurl  = "http://parentdomain.domain.com:80/jde/servlet/com.jdedwards.portal.PortalBuilderServlet";
    buildurl += "?&launchAction=launchForm&OID="+formID;
    buildurl += document.jdeowpFormInterconnect;        
    buildurl += "&jdeowpcompstate=2";
    buildurl += "&stackId=" + formID + escape((new Date()).getTime());
    buildurl += "&jdeowpcompclass=com.jdedwards.runtime.virtual.HTMLClientPortalComponent";
    buildurl += "&jdeowpcompname=jdeowpc000";   
    window.open(buildurl,"jdeerphostedapplication","scrollbars=1,directories=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes");
}


function addRunOWAppFI(templ,values)
{
    document.jdeowpFormInterconnect = "&FormDSTmpl=" + templ;
    document.jdeowpFormInterconnect+= "&FormDSData="+ values;
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT>
function jdeowpHandleLoad()
{
    jdeowponloadjdeowpc000();
}
function jdeowpHandleResize(namespace)
{
    jdeowponresizejdeowpc000(namespace);
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY style="OVERFLOW: hidden">
<DIV align=center width="100%">
<TABLE class=tallAndWideTable cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=tallAndWideTable vAlign=top>
<TABLE class=tallAndWideTable cellSpacing=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD vAlign=top width="100%">
<SCRIPT>
            function jdeowponloadjdeowpc000(){
                 
                        }
                        function jdeowponresizejdeowpc000(namespace){
                                
            }
            </SCRIPT>

<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD width="100%">
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 width="100%">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=GroupHeading width="100%">Media Object Viewer</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD id=OWPComponent class=component>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="/jde/ResourceCanonicalsJS.mafService?e1.namespace=&amp;e1.service=ResourceCanonicalsJS&amp;RENDER_MAFLET=E1Menu&amp;e1.state=maximized&amp;e1.mode=view"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="/jde/share/js/e1.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT>

_e1URLFactory = new E1URLFactory('Servlet','/jde/','/jde/URLBuilderService.mafService?e1.namespace=&e1.service=URLBuilderService&RENDER_MAFLET=E1Menu&e1.state=maximized&e1.mode=view');

</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="/jde/js/JSComponent.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="/jde/js/Form.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="/jde/js/MOViewer.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="/jde/js/JDEDTA.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT>var disableRightAltKey = "true";</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT>var PSFT_TE_NAMESPACE='';

function LaunchHotKeysPage()
{
    window.open("/jde/JspDispatcher.mafService?E1_JSP_PATH_PARAM=%2Fowhtml%2FHotKeys.jsp&e1.namespace=&e1.service=JspDispatcher&RENDER_MAFLET=E1Menu&e1.state=maximized&stackId=1644345435180&e1.mode=view", "Hotkey_Summary","titlebar, resizable=1, scrollbars=1");
}</SCRIPT>

<FORM style="MARGIN: 0px" method=post name=prot action=/jde/servlet/com.jdedwards.portal.PortalBuilderServlet?jdeowpcompname=jdeowpc000&amp;jdeowpcompclass=com.jdedwards.runtime.virtual.HTMLClientPortalComponent&amp;jdeowpcompstate=2&amp;stackId=1644345435180&amp;RID=976953a374897ab4><INPUT type=hidden value="test val" name=visit><INPUT type=hidden value="test val" name=RID></FORM>
<SCRIPT>var szWaitMsg = "Waiting for your request to process. Do you want to refresh?"</SCRIPT>

<FORM method=post name=MOOption action=/jde/servlet/com.jdedwards.portal.PortalBuilderServlet?jdeowpcompname=jdeowpc000&amp;jdeowpcompclass=com.jdedwards.runtime.virtual.HTMLClientPortalComponent&amp;jdeowpcompstate=2&amp;stackId=1644345435180&amp;RID=976953a374897ab4><INPUT type=hidden value="test val" name=activeXSupported><INPUT type=hidden value="test val" name=moItemType> <INPUT type=hidden value="test val" name=cmdMO> <INPUT type=hidden value="test val" name=pgIDKey>
<SCRIPT> var mafLoopURL = "/jde/servlet/com.jdedwards.portal.PortalBuilderServlet?jdeowpcompname=jdeowpc000&jdeowpcompclass=com.jdedwards.runtime.virtual.HTMLClientPortalComponent&jdeowpcompstate=2&stackId=1644345435180&RID=976953a374897ab4"; var mafCloseURL = "null";</SCRIPT>
<INPUT type=hidden value="test val" name=stackId><INPUT type=hidden value="test val" name=RID>
<SCRIPT></SCRIPT>
 
<TABLE id=WebMenuBarFrame class=MenuBar cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=1 width="100%">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD noWrap><A href="#content"><IMG border=0 alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="/jde/share/images/login/1pix_shim.gif"></A>
<TABLE id=WebMenuBar style="POSITION: relative" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD vAlign=top align=center><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/jde/share/images/spacer.gif" width=35 height=1><BR>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER>
<DIV id=div title="Save (Ctrl+Alt+V)" style="OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 35px; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; TEXT-ALIGN: center"><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt">Sa<U>v</U>e</FONT></DIV></CENTER></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER><A tabIndex=-1 title="Save (Ctrl+Alt+V)" style="TEXT-DECORATION: none"><IMG onclick="MOCmd('SAVEEXIT')" onmouseover="this.src='/jde/img/hc1mo.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='/jde/img/hc1.gif'" id=BUTTONSAVEEXIT style="CURSOR: pointer" border=0 name=BUTTONSAVEEXIT alt="Save (Ctrl+Alt+V)" src="/jde/img/hc1.gif" align=absMiddle></A></CENTER></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD vAlign=top align=center><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/jde/share/images/spacer.gif" width=35 height=1><BR>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER>
<DIV id=div title="Cancel (Ctrl+Alt+L)" style="OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 35px; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; TEXT-ALIGN: center"><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt">Cance<U>l</U></FONT></DIV></CENTER></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER><A tabIndex=-1 title="Cancel (Ctrl+Alt+L)" style="TEXT-DECORATION: none"><IMG onclick="MOCmd('CANCEL')" onmouseover="this.src='/jde/img/hc2mo.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='/jde/img/hc2.gif'" id=BUTTONCANCEL style="CURSOR: pointer" border=0 name=BUTTONCANCEL alt="Cancel (Ctrl+Alt+L)" src="/jde/img/hc2.gif" align=absMiddle></A></CENTER></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD vAlign=top align=center><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/jde/share/images/spacer.gif" width=35 height=1><BR>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER>
<DIV id=div title="Text (Ctrl+Alt+X)" style="OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 35px; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; TEXT-ALIGN: center"><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt">Te<U>x</U>t</FONT></DIV></CENTER></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER><A tabIndex=-1 title="Text (Ctrl+Alt+X)" style="TEXT-DECORATION: none"><IMG onclick="MOCmd('ADDTEXT')" onmouseover="this.src='/jde/img/addtxtmo.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='/jde/img/addtxt.gif'" id=BUTTONADDTEXT style="CURSOR: pointer" border=0 name=BUTTONADDTEXT alt="Text (Ctrl+Alt+X)" src="/jde/img/addtxt.gif" align=absMiddle></A></CENTER></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD vAlign=top align=center><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/jde/share/images/spacer.gif" width=35 height=1><BR>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER>
<DIV id=div title="File (Ctrl+Alt+I)" style="OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 35px; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; TEXT-ALIGN: center"><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt">F<U>i</U>le</FONT></DIV></CENTER></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER><A tabIndex=-1 title="File (Ctrl+Alt+I)" style="TEXT-DECORATION: none"><IMG onclick="MOCmd('ADDIMAGE')" onmouseover="this.src='/jde/img/addimgmo.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='/jde/img/addimg.gif'" id=BUTTONADDIMAGE style="CURSOR: pointer" border=0 name=BUTTONADDIMAGE alt="File (Ctrl+Alt+I)" src="/jde/img/addimg.gif" align=absMiddle></A></CENTER></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD vAlign=top align=center><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/jde/share/images/spacer.gif" width=35 height=1><BR>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER>
<DIV id=div title="URL (Ctrl+Alt+U)" style="OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 35px; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; TEXT-ALIGN: center"><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt"><U>U</U>RL</FONT></DIV></CENTER></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER><A tabIndex=-1 title="URL (Ctrl+Alt+U)" style="TEXT-DECORATION: none"><IMG onclick="MOCmd('ADDURL')" onmouseover="this.src='/jde/img/addurlmo.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='/jde/img/addurl.gif'" id=BUTTONADDURL style="CURSOR: pointer" border=0 name=BUTTONADDURL alt="URL (Ctrl+Alt+U)" src="/jde/img/addurl.gif" align=absMiddle></A></CENTER></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD vAlign=top align=center><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/jde/share/images/spacer.gif" width=35 height=1><BR>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER>
<DIV id=div title="OLE (Ctrl+Alt+O)" style="OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 35px; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; TEXT-ALIGN: center"><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt"><U>O</U>LE</FONT></DIV></CENTER></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER><A tabIndex=-1 title="OLE (Ctrl+Alt+O)" style="TEXT-DECORATION: none"><IMG onclick="MOCmd('ADDOLE')" onmouseover="this.src='/jde/img/addolemo.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='/jde/img/addole.gif'" id=BUTTONADDOLE style="CURSOR: pointer" border=0 name=BUTTONADDOLE alt="OLE (Ctrl+Alt+O)" src="/jde/img/addole.gif" align=absMiddle></A></CENTER></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD vAlign=top align=center><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/jde/share/images/spacer.gif" width=35 height=1><BR>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER>
<DIV id=div title="Templates (Ctrl+Alt+M)" style="OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 35px; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; TEXT-ALIGN: center"><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt">Te<U>m</U>plates</FONT></DIV></CENTER></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER><A tabIndex=-1 title="Templates (Ctrl+Alt+M)" style="TEXT-DECORATION: none"><IMG onclick="MOCmd('TEMPLATE')" onmouseover="this.src='/jde/img/tmplmo.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='/jde/img/tmpl.gif'" id=BUTTONTEMPLATE style="CURSOR: pointer" border=0 name=BUTTONTEMPLATE alt="Templates (Ctrl+Alt+M)" src="/jde/img/tmpl.gif" align=absMiddle></A></CENTER></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD vAlign=top align=center><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/jde/share/images/spacer.gif" width=35 height=1><BR>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER>
<DIV id=div title="Characterize (Ctrl+Alt+Z)" style="OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 35px; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; TEXT-ALIGN: center"><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt">Characteri<U>z</U>e</FONT></DIV></CENTER></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER><A tabIndex=-1 title="Characterize (Ctrl+Alt+Z)" style="TEXT-DECORATION: none"><IMG onclick="MOCmd('CHARACTERIZE')" onmouseover="this.src='/jde/img/charmo.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='/jde/img/char.gif'" id=BUTTONCHARACTERIZE style="CURSOR: pointer" border=0 name=BUTTONCHARACTERIZE alt="Characterize (Ctrl+Alt+Z)" src="/jde/img/char.gif" align=absMiddle></A></CENTER></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD vAlign=top align=center><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/jde/share/images/spacer.gif" width=35 height=1><BR>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER>
<DIV id=div title="Delete (Ctrl+Alt+D)" style="OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 35px; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; TEXT-ALIGN: center"><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt"><U>D</U>elete</FONT></DIV></CENTER></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD noWrap>
<CENTER><A tabIndex=-1 title="Delete (Ctrl+Alt+D)" style="TEXT-DECORATION: none"><IMG onclick="MOCmd('DELETE')" onmouseover="this.src='/jde/img/hc952mo.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='/jde/img/hc952.gif'" id=BUTTONDELETE style="CURSOR: pointer" border=0 name=BUTTONDELETE alt="Delete (Ctrl+Alt+D)" src="/jde/img/hc952.gif" align=absMiddle></A></CENTER></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD><A name=content></A></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<SCRIPT>
var accKeys = new Array('86','76','88','73','85','79','77','90','68');
var accIDs = new Array('SAVEEXIT','CANCEL','ADDTEXT','ADDIMAGE','ADDURL','ADDOLE','TEMPLATE','CHARACTERIZE','DELETE');
</SCRIPT>

<DIV onscroll=FormDivScrollHandler.syncToolBar() tabIndex=-1 id=e1formDiv style="OVERFLOW: auto; HEIGHT: 100%; WIDTH: 100%">
<TABLE id=e1WCTable cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" summary="" border=0 valign="top">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD style="HEIGHT: 100%; WIDTH: 120px" vAlign=top>
<TABLE id=NavBar class=MenuBar height="100%" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=120 summary="" border=0 valign="top">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD vAlign=top align=center>
<TABLE id=NavBarInner cellSpacing=2 cellPadding=2 summary="" border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD tabIndex=-1 class=ActiveItem style="BORDER-TOP: gray 2px outset; BORDER-RIGHT: gray 2px outset; BORDER-BOTTOM: gray 2px outset; BORDER-LEFT: gray 2px outset; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff" align=center>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 110px; OVERFLOW-X: hidden; TEXT-OVERFLOW: ellipsis"><IMG onclick="MOCmd('ACTIVATE0')" id=moItemText1 border=0 alt=Text src="/jde/img/text.gif"><BR><SPAN onclick=renameItem(this) id=ActiveItemText>Text1</SPAN><BR></DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TD id=e1WCTD>
<TABLE id=MOItem height="100%" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" summary="" border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD align=center><INPUT type=hidden value="test val" name=textModified> <LABEL for=motext><SPAN style="DISPLAY: none">Media Object Text</SPAN></LABEL> <TEXTAREA id=motext style="DISPLAY: none" rows=30 cols=60 name=motext></TEXTAREA>
<SCRIPT>
        function window_onresize()
        {
       if ((window.adfpp_handleLocationChange) &&
            (!window.AdfPortletContextualEvent))
{           var width = getWindowWidth();
            var height = getWindowHeight()-230;
            var navBar1 = document.all["NavBar"];
            width = width - navBar1.offsetWidth-15;
             var moItm = document.getElementById('MOItem');
            moItm.height=height+15;
            moItm.width=width+15;
}else {
            var width = document.body.scrollWidth;
            var height = document.body.offsetHeight-230;
            var navBar = document.all["NavBar"];
            width = width - navBar.offsetWidth - 15;
            if(height < document.body.scrollHeight-230)
                height = document.body.scrollHeight-230;
}
            if(document.MOOption.jdeRTF){
            if(width > 530)
            document.MOOption.jdeRTF.width = width;
            else
            document.MOOption.jdeRTF.width = 530;
            document.MOOption.jdeRTF.height = height;
}
            if ((window.adfpp_handleLocationChange) &&
                (!window.AdfPortletContextualEvent))
            {
             var moItm = document.getElementById('MOItem');
            moItm.height=height+15;
            moItm.width=width+15;
                var ocStr;
                ocStr = "JSCompMgr.positionE1FormDiv('')";
                setTimeout(ocStr,1000);
            }
            else
            {
                JSCompMgr.positionE1FormDiv('');
            }
        }
        window.onresize = window_onresize;
        </SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=javascript for=jdeRTF event=postCreate>
        document.MOOption.jdeRTF.SetData(document.MOOption.motext.value);
        window_onresize();
        g_bRTFEdit = true;
        </SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=javascript for=jdeRTF event=requestFocus>
        document.MOOption.jdeRTF.setActive();
        document.MOOption.jdeRTF.SetRTFFocus();
        </SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=javascript for=jdeRTF event=performSpellCheck>
alert('The spelling check functionality is not supported for current language preference setting.');        </SCRIPT>

<OBJECT id=jdeRTF codeBase="/jde/axctls/jdewebctlsU.cab#version=8970,2010,09,30" classid=clsid:B1D21FC5-A742-4261-86F2-C7B7F1A31C5D width=1393 height=182><PARAM NAME="_Version" VALUE="65536"><PARAM NAME="_ExtentX" VALUE="36856"><PARAM NAME="_ExtentY" VALUE="4815"><PARAM NAME="_StockProps" VALUE="10"><PARAM NAME="Caption" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="ForeColor" VALUE="0">
        ActiveX control for Media Objects</OBJECT>
<SCRIPT>setTimeout("document.MOOption.jdeRTF.setActive();document.MOOption.jdeRTF.SetRTFFocus();", 1000);</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT>var spellCheckIsCompleteMsg = "The spelling check is complete.";</SCRIPT>
</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV>
<SCRIPT defer>
</SCRIPT>
</FORM>
<SCRIPT>
function OnLoadMethods()
{
window_onresize();

}
</SCRIPT>
<NOSCRIPT></NOSCRIPT></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><IMG src="/jde/owportal/images/spacer.gif" width=7 align=center height=7> </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

So I'm stuck. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.jdelist.com/community/forums/

Comment: @QHarr, yep found this forum recently. I'll ask there. Thanks for the tip.